# Is it possible with spring-cloud-contract to work on a contract branch for the producer?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

Currently we have a github repo where we store all the contracts, another repo which contains the producer code, and last but not least another one which contains the consumer code.

On the consumer side working with branches when pointing to the contract repo is well supported by using properties like stubrunner.properties.git.branch (more info can be found here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/appendix.html#additional-application-properties)

**But** on the producer I can not see any way of using the contracts of a concrete branch, we just can point to the github repo where contracts are stored by using contractsRepositoryUrl of the spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin

This will be very useful to create a flow of contract testing :

- a PR to contract testing repo with the proposal
- which will trigger the producer job (passing the pr branch name)
- if the repo with the contracts contains the bindings, populated by the producer(previous step), then we could trigger the consumer job and validate if everything is fine with these proposed changes
- once the 2 builds are green (producer and consumer) we can merge the changes on the contracts repo

UPDATE : the following spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin config worked for me, also you can set this property through command line like this -Dstubrunner.properties.git.branch=other_branch_than_master

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <baseClassMappings>
                    <baseClassMapping>
                        <contractPackageRegex>.*rest.*</contractPackageRegex>
                        <baseClassFQN>com.xxx.yyy.contract.ContentCheckBaseTestClass</baseClassFQN>
                    </baseClassMapping>
                </baseClassMappings>
                <basePackageForTests>com.xxx.yyy.contract</basePackageForTests>

                <contractsRepositoryUrl>git://https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git</contractsRepositoryUrl>
                <contractsRepositoryUsername>${GITHUB_USER}</contractsRepositoryUsername>
                <contractsRepositoryPassword>${GITHUB_TOKEN}</contractsRepositoryPassword>
                <contractsMode>REMOTE</contractsMode>
                <testMode>EXPLICIT</testMode>
                <testFramework>JUNIT5</testFramework>
                    
                <contractsProperties> 
                  <git.branch>another_branch</git.branch>
                </contractsProperties>

                <contractDependency>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                </contractDependency>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>pushStubsToScm</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse the same properties presented here (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix.html#additional-application-properties) under the e.g. Spring Cloud Contract Maven's  `<configuration><contractProperties>` section. That way you can pick which branch should be downloaded. Inside the plugin configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <contractsProperties>
        <git.branch>branchname</git.branch>
    </contractsProperties>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I was testing the solution and maybe I did not fully get the idea but the contractProperties approach did not work for me, I edited the question

Comment: Set git.branch instead of stubrunner.

Comment: yep, that was the problem but also a small typo <contractsProperties> with ending 's' in 'contracts' , actually I think that the documentation also refers to it as singular. I update the sample config to reflect what worked for me, thanks!